# Tree like view for xml in web browser

Tags: javascript, css, treeview

I have xml data(file or text) sent to client from web server.
The xml has tags only (no attributes). Actually I am using it to represent a tree.
On client side I need to render it as a tree and let client select multiple nodes in tree and submit it back to web server.
Are there any useful resources out there I can use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a bird view I would suggest you using XSL for transforming XML to XHTML code (you can play around here: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog - description here: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/)

For tree components you could use for example a jQuery plugin (http://floatmargin.com/demos/checkboxtree/checkboxtree.html).

Edit: 
the above link does not work. You may find plenty of checkbox trees in jQuery by Googling as I see. Though I did not try each out. E.g.: http://www.redcarrot.co.uk/2009/11/11/collapsible-checkbox-tree-jquery-plugin/

Comment: Thanks.. the example is perfect for my use case !!

Comment: Unfortunately last link doesn't work anymore. Could you find it again? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

See:

**[Generating a tree view using XSL and XML](http://www.tonymarston.net/xml-xsl/xml-and-xsl-treeview.html)**